# Most efficient way to find repeated elements in different vectors

Tags: c++, vector, compare

I have a vector of strings that contains 5 elements called bottledNotes. I'm trying to find in a vector class called products, which inside has a vector of strings called productNames, what elements of bottledNotes are in productNames of each product.

Ideally I would like to sort my results out in terms of repetition. Meaning, if the bottledNotes are repeated 5 times then return me that product. This is my first approach:

```
vector <Products> ofApp::returnProductsSuggestions(vector<Products> &_notesProducts, vector<string> &_bottledNotes){

vector<Products> newProducts;

for( int i = 0; i < _notesProducts.size(); i++){
//        cout << "We made it into to the products" << endl;
 for( int j = 0; j < _notesProducts[i].productNotes.size(); j++){
//        cout << "We made it into to the productNotes" << endl;
    for ( int k = 0; k < _bottledNotes.size(); k++){

        if( five of the bottleNotes are repeated in the productNotes){

           newProducts.push_back(_notesProducts[i]);
        }

        if( four of the bottleNotes are repeated in the productNotes){

           newProducts.push_back(_notesProducts[i]);
        }

           //etc...

        if ( _notesProducts[i].productNotes[j] == _bottledNotes[k] && i == 0){// we chec in the first set of products
//               cout << "These are the notes that are included in the first product: " << _bottledNotes[k] << endl;                    
             break;                                 }               
        }            
    }        
}

 return _notesProducts;
}
```

Is there any way to do this with this method? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Investigate `std::set_intersection`.

Comment: Also, wouldn't a `std::map<std::string, int>` be more appropriate for this? The string is the name, and the `int` would be the count.

Comment: @PaulMkKenzie   I get the concept of set_intersection, I'm just having a hard time using it multiple times. All examples I have found they just show two vectors. Also, why would the map container be better? Care to ellaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Think conceptually.  You want to store multiple copies of a string, and then count how many multiples there are.  The appropriate (or better) container is a `std::map`.  The reason is that you have just one string and attached to that one string, a count of the number of times the string occurs.  The vector is clunky with all of those copies, and probably not optimal.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   Thanks a lot! It makes a lot of sense now. I was actually able to figure I out!